# Eclipse Error: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe How to Solve?

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt

I am using GWT2.0.1,when I am running web application then I get following error message on Console. after removing error from error log still same message occur as well as restarting eclipse_galileo.To solve this problem i want to restart machine.
Each time this message comes on console,then i need to restart m/c

 **I there any way to solve this problem ?** 

please provide best solution? ASAP.

> Exception in thread "Code server for Dealelephant from Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.17) Gecko/2010010604 Ubuntu/9.04 (jaunty) Firefox/3.0.17 on http://127.0.0.1:8888/Dealelephant.html?gwt.codesvr=127.0.0.1:9997 @ Ci%#*k,XE'=JH,|~" com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$RemoteDeathError: Remote connection lost
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:391)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.run(BrowserChannelServer.java:222)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
>   Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Broken pipe
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
>       at java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:136)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:65)
>       at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:123)
>       at java.io.DataOutputStream.flush(DataOutputStream.java:106)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannel$ReturnMessage.send(BrowserChannel.java:1341)
>       at com.google.gwt.dev.shell.BrowserChannelServer.processConnection(BrowserChannelServer.java:388)
>       ... 2 more

Hope for Best co-operation
Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is very tricky issue and I spent a day to find out what's going on.

The problem in my case was infinite recursion which led to `StackOverflowError` (deep copy constructor with cyclic dependency). Mostly it just died on `RemoteDeathError`, but when I was stepping through the code, sometimes it printed uncaught exception log (SOE) to gwt console before RDE. This kind of error is fatal to VM so you are lucky if it can even log it to gwt console. I suppose it kills the browser plugin thread, so gwt codeserver complains about lost connection. So my advice is to check your client side code for infinite recursion.